# Add 0 and 1 is alternate array cells in java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have any array with value 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1
Now my required output should be like each zero will be in odd index and 1 will be in even and if 0 left after that it should be copied after 1 and viceversa.
Means the output will be 0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0....
**But the above operation must be done in a single pass of array**

- So I created an array with same size ,
- then I started traversing the main array and one's 0 is encoutered I put a counter to set the value in odd index and viceversa
- In the end when the index crossed the length of new array created , I started adding the 0 into the new cell in even mode from backward.

What can be the other better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need an extra array for this. You can do it in-place. Just keep two pointers, one which stops after every odd step and one which finds the `1s`. When the second pointer encounters a `1` just swap it with the first pointer, increment the first pointer. Do this for the length of the array.

Comment: one doubt in the put is like 1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1 then how to manage as pointer will cross the index of array

Comment: :D No, the first pointer will not move at all since it only moves after a `swap()`. Also, this is where you improvise on my solution. A simple `if()` condition will do the trick. All you have to do is `1. To check if the digits at both pointers differ` and `2. If the swap has to be made or not even though they differ.` Hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try inplace in one pass

Keep one pointer at the beginning of the array and one at the end of the array.

I am assuming that number of zeroes is greater than number of ones

```
int begin = 0, end = length - 1;
while (begin < end){
    if (A[begin] == 0 && A[end] == 1){
        if (begin % 2 != 0){
            int tmp = A[end];
            A[end] = A[begin];
            A[begin] = temp;
            end--;
        }
        begin++;
    }
    else
        break;
}
```

Remember, above solution won't work for cases when number of ones is greater than number of zeroes

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int arr[]={1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1};
    int n=10;
    int odd,one,tmp;
    odd=one=0;

    while(true)
    {
        while(odd<n && arr[odd])
            odd+=2;
        while(one<n && (((one<=odd)&&(one%2==0)) || !arr[one]))
            one++;

       if(odd<n && one<n)
       {
           arr[one]=arr[one]^arr[odd];
           arr[odd]=arr[one]^arr[odd];
           arr[one]=arr[one]^arr[odd];
       }
       else
           break;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
}
```